# Google Drive API: Enforce File Ownership on Shared Folder

Tags: api, google-app-engine, directory, shared, drive

My Problem: My app creates a folder with some files that it shares with other accounts. This works fine as long as the other accounts just update the existing files. But when they create new files, these are owned by that account and the sharing account (e.g. my app) has no access to them.

So my question is: Is there a way I can enforce that all files created in or copied to the shared folder are owned by the account that created the folder, or that account has at least r/w - access to that files (like SetGID on directories with Unix/Linux)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: **[Here’s](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/7166529)** what people can do with folders after you share it with them. This is the **[documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-sharing)** for sharing files, folders and drives. Maybe Permission propagation can help you, and you can verify user permissions and change them accordingly. Hope you find it helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. While it doesn't show the perfect solution it surely points into the right direction..